# Cannot get element to overlap another

Tags: css, wordpress, element, overlap

I have a Divi WordPress website http://linden.flywheelsites.com and I'm trying to get element ID "atlas_menu1" to overlap all other elements on the page. Somehow the element "et-page-area" or "main-content" still overlap the atlas_menu1.

Can anyone take a look at the page inspector and see if you can find a solution? I can give access if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Consider looking at the [z-index CSS Property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: I have, no matter what I've done with all other elements being lower z-index and the one atlas_menu1 higher, results in the same thing.

Comment: @MatthewWalker What browser are you testing in, because I couldn't reproduce it with Chrome or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

Could you look at .et_pb_text_3? It has display: none. Sorry for this answer. I can't comment yet.

Answer (score 0):

Remember, elements with z-index only "works" when it's on the same level.

For example:

```css
.parent{position:absolute;width:100px;height:100px;}
.child{background:red;position:absolute;width:50px;height:50px;margin:auto;top:0;right:0;bottom:0;left:0;z-index:999999;}
.first{z-index:1;background:blue;}
.second{z-index:2;left:50px;top:50px;background:yellow;}
.third{z-index:3;left:100px;top:100px;background:green;}
.fourth{z-index:4;left:150px;top:150px;background:purple;}
```

```html
<div class="parent first">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent second">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent third">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent fourth">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

All child class has a z-index of 999999, yet, the parent class with lower z-index, stays on top of the child's. That's because once you have nested z-index elements, a child element can't overlap a parent element.

In you case, `#atlas_menu1(z-index:9999)` is inside `.et_pb_row_2(z-index:1)` that is inside `.et_pb_section_4(z-index:-1)`

Try removing the `.et_pb_section_4` and `.et_pb_text_3` z-index, then set `.et_pb_row_2` z-index to 99999.